# Common saying in English when someone is being scolded for not doing their part or being lazy

Tags: popular-refrains

I'm simply reaching out with a query in regards to common English saying. For life of me, I'm unable to recall the entire phrase people typically use when stating a fact about someone, who is not doing their job well and other people are discussing this person's lack of initiation.

I've heard people typically say "something something, if he had to get up and do it".

Update:
Thank you all for wonderful inputs. "Tinfoil Hat" hit it on the head with correct answer i was looking for.
"Weather Vane"s response has come the closest to common phrase i'm eyeing. I feel we're getting closer. You see it's like when someone says "And God help us all, if he/she had to get up and do something". It's like a snarky saying. I'm looking for the part that people say instead of "And God help us all

Comment: "shirker "and "slacker"

Comment: Maybe something like: *He can't fight his way out of a paper bag.*

Comment: Do you mean "lack of initiative"?

Comment: About common sayings: "For life of me" should be "For ***the*** life of me".

Comment: *God forbid [he should have to do it]?*

Comment: All: **Answers should not go in comments. They can be removed at the drop of a hat.** @Anonymous Please don't use edits like this. Edit your question with new information (if it doesn't radically change it) but keep it as a coherent question.

Answer (score 0):

There are idioms such as

> **As much use as a chocolate teapot**
> Utterly useless or ineffectual (because pouring boiling water into a chocolate teapot would melt it).

From [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+much+use+as+a+chocolate+teapot)

Answer (score 0):

One option to describe someone who doesn't pull his or her weight might be **bone-idle**, which the Cambridge Dictionary defines as:

> extremely lazy

Alternatively, you might prefer **work-shy**:

> (of a person) lazy and disinclined to work.